# animate one object into another addon?

Tags: add-on

So a few months ago, I came across an addon that would give you the ability to animate the transformation of one object to another by taking apart the faces of the 1st object, morphing them, and then positioning them into the shape of the 2nd object. But I can't seem to find it again! Does anyone know what this addon is called? any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Was it this? http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?263719-Particle-Morphing-Tools-%28First-Part-Updated%29

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Thank you! Is there any way to download it? the zip file link just brings be to a 404 page

Comment: Hm.. This thread seems to have some info: http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?263719-Particle-Morphing-Tools-%28First-Part-Updated%29/page5

Comment: At the end I only have found this custom build: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?289299-Morph-Modifier, but I can't download it.

Comment: Oh well, maybe someday it will be redone.